# create a folder with a user defined name in batch

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch code, where if I enter a number "11" and then a text "ss" then it should create a folder name as "**11-ss**", within the folder I need 3 folders named 1, 2, 3.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir %1-%2\1
mkdir %1-%2\2
mkdir %1-%2\3
```

Save this as batch and call it by
`batchfile.bat 11 ss`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set /p number=enter the number:
set /p text=enter the text:
md %number%-%text%\1 %number%-%text%\3 %number%-%text%\1
```

this is an interactive solution ...